# Using rvest to creating a database from multiple XML files

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

Using R to extract relevant data from multiple online XML files to create a database

I just started to learn R to do text analysis. Here is what I am trying to do: I'm trying to use rvest in r to create a CSV database of bill summaries from the 116th Congress from online XML files. The database should have two columns:

1. The title of the bill.
2. The summary text of the bill.

The website source is https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/BILLSUM/116/hr

The issue I am having is

I would like to collect all the speeches that are returned from the search. So I need to web scrape multiple links. But I don't know how to ensure that r runs function with a series of different links and then extract the expected data.

I have tried the following code but I am not sure how exactly to apply them to my specific problem. Also, I got an error report of my code. Please see my code below. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
library(rvest)    
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
html_source <- "https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/BILLSUM/116/hr?page="


map_df(1:997, function(i) {  

  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(html_source, i))

  data.frame(title = html_text(html_nodes(pg, "title")),
             bill_text %>% html_node("summary-text") %>% html_text(),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

}) -> Bills
```

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 406.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of that page is a link to a zipfile with all of the XML files, so instead of scraping each one individually (which will get onerous with [a suggested crawl-delay of 10s](https://www.govinfo.gov/robots.txt)) you can just download the zipfile and parse the XML files with xml2 (rvest is for HTML):

```r
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

local_dir <- "~/Downloads/BILLSUM-116-hr"
local_zip <- paste0(local_dir, '.zip')

download.file("https://www.govinfo.gov/bulkdata/BILLSUM/116/hr/BILLSUM-116-hr.zip", local_zip)
# returns vector of paths to unzipped files
xml_files <- unzip(local_zip, exdir = local_dir)

bills <- xml_files %>%
    map(read_xml) %>% 
    map_dfr(~list(
        # note xml2 functions only take XPath selectors, not CSS ones
        title = xml_find_first(.x, '//title') %>% xml_text(),
        summary = xml_find_first(.x, '//summary-text') %>% xml_text()
    ))

bills
#> # A tibble: 1,367 x 2
#>    title                               summary                             
#>    <chr>                               <chr>                               
#>  1 For the relief of certain aliens w… Provides for the relief of certain …
#>  2 "To designate the facility of the … "Designates the facility of the Uni…
#>  3 Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2… <p><b>Consolidated Appropriations A…
#>  4 Financial Institution Customer Pro… <p><strong>Financial Institution Cu…
#>  5 Zero-Baseline Budget Act of 2019    <p><b>Zero-Baseline Budget Act of 2…
#>  6 Agriculture, Rural Development, Fo… "<p><b>Highlights: </b></p> <p>This…
#>  7 SAFETI Act                          <p><strong>Security for the Adminis…
#>  8 Buy a Brick, Build the Wall Act of… <p><b>Buy a Brick, Build the Wall A…
#>  9 Inspector General Access Act of 20… <p><strong>Inspector General Access…
#> 10 Federal CIO Authorization Act of 2… <p><b>Federal CIO Authorization Act…
#> # … with 1,357 more rows
```

The `summary` column is HTML-formatted, but by and large this is pretty clean already.

Comment: Hi Alistaire, sorry to reply you late. Thanks so much for your help. It works perfectly! Also, I tried to figure it out myself, which is quite similar to your codes. Would you mind my asking two following questions with your codes?

Comment: 1) I didn't see your definition of ".x", so does it refer to all files extracted from the website? Is it default? 2) How about the difference between XPath selectors and CSS ones? Again, many many thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. `~ .x` is [a purrr shorthand](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) for an anonymous function, which could also be written `function(x) x`. In this case, then, it's iterating over read-in XML files, so `.x` is a single file.

Comment: 2. With XML you have to use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) to select the nodes you care about. With HTML (through rvest), you can use either XPath or [CSS selectors](https://flukeout.github.io/) (which are not as powerful, but are easier to write). In this case you know the exact node name, so you can use `//{node name}` to search anywhere in the DOM for nodes named `{node name}`.

Comment: Hi Alistaire, thanks so much for your replies. It helps a lot!